# Skype4Com on Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use Skype4COM api C# on a Windows8 machine using Visual Studio 2012 RC ide. I'm not even able to create the Skype object because of this error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
{830690FC-BF2F-47A6-AC2D-330BCB402664}using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to 
the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). 
Please make sure your COM object is in the allowed 
list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp.
```

I also tried to register the ddl with no success.... if I try to use the api with Visual studio 2010 there are no porblems....

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Firstly ensure you've registered the COM dll:

`regsvr32 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype\Skype4COM.dll`

Secondly, ensure that you're building for (x86): Build configuration tab for the project.